# codeabbey : list index out of range

Tags: python

Here is the question:
Let us calculate sum of digits, as earlier, but multiplying each digit by its position (counting from the left, starting from 1). For example, given the value 1776 we calculate such weighted sum of digits (let us call it "wsd") as:

wsd(1776) = 1 * 1 + 7 * 2 + 7 * 3 + 6 * 4 = 60

Here is my code:

```
digitlist = []
numlist = []
def splitdigit(number):
    numlist = []
    digitlist = []
    numlist.append(number)
    while number >= 1:
        number = number/10
        numlist.append(number)
    del numlist[-1]
    for ele in numlist:
        digitlist.append(ele%10)
    return digitlist
# digit part

# test if the split digit work here:
# print (splitdigit(1234))  it works
times = int(input())
raw = raw_input()
string = raw.split()
nlist = []
outbox = []
rout = 0
res = 0
n = 0


for item in string:
    nlist.append(int(item))
# print (nlist) [it worked]
for element in nlist:
    # check for split method : checked
    # formula to make the digit work: n = len(out) | while(n>1): n=n-1 
    # rout=out[-n]*n res=res+rout(res=0)
    n = len(splitdigit(element))
    print (n)
    res = 0
    while n >= 1:
        rout = (splitdigit(element)[(n*(-1))]) * n     # I HAVEN"T CHECK THIS FORMULA OUT !!!
        res = res + rout
        n = n + 1
    outbox.append(res)
    print (outbox)
print(" ".join(str(x) for x in outbox))
```

And here is my running error:

```
> 3
9 15 1776
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "13.py", line 39, in <module>
    rout = splitdigit(element)[(n*(-1))] * n     # I HAVEN"T CHECK THIS FORMULA OUT !!!
IndexError: list index out of range
```

and I checked it in interactive python. I think I am not asking for a item out of range but it gives me this error. I hope someone can help me out. Thank you, love you all.

Comment: You increase `n` forever, so yes, it'll run out of range. `while n >= 1` is never going to be *false* if all you do is `n = n + 1`.

Comment: OH! YEAH it should be n = n - 1. Thank you so much haha

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking way too complicated.

```
def wsd(number):
    digits = [int(i) for i in str(number)]
    result = 0
    for index, value in enumerate(digits):
        result += (index + 1) * value
    return result

print(wsd(1776))
```

Output:

```
60
```

Comment: Or, if `value = 1776` it's just `sum(pos * int(digit) for pos, digit in enumerate(str(value), start=1))`